# How to find system's audio driver status onloading of html5 page

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I have a HTML5 page which has voice-over. It is playing the video perfectly on loading the page. I need to check the system's audio driver status, If it is disabled, i need to pop a message box saying "Audio driver is disabled". If it is enabled nothing to do.

My HTML5 code to add audio.

```
<audio preload="auto" id="Scene 1.0"><source src="sounds/Scene 1.0.mp3"></audio>
```

Comment: I think its not possible. You only can query if the browser dosnt support HTML audio.

Comment: All the browsers are supporting HTML audio. I checked that already.  My need is to check the system's audio driver status, if it is disabled i wanted to give message box to the user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot ([yet](http://www.w3.org/TR/audio-output/)) get the audio outputs from `HTMLMediaElement`.

However, you can try creating a new `AudioContext` ([browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/AudioContext#Browser_compatibility)), then check its destination property. I believe that if the `maxChannelCount`property is less than 1, then the driver is not instantiated.

```js
function check_audioOut(){
  if(!window.AudioContext) return 'not accessible';
  var audioCtx = new AudioContext();
  return (audioCtx.destination.maxChannelCount>0)?'enabled': 'disabled';
  }

document.body.innerHTML = 'audio driver ' + check_audioOut();
```

**Note that you won't be able to check if it is muted or not.**

Comment: I tried with your code. its simple and fantastic but first It has given output as driver is enabled. second time i disabled the audio driver, but your code still giving as driver is enabled. What to do?

Comment: how did you disabled the driver? I tried on win7 with disabling it in the device manager and it worked in FF

Comment: Even i did the same. But i disabled only the High definition Audio device the second option but not ATI high definition Audio Device.

Comment: So you still had an audio driver enabled, so the code still worked

Comment: yeah it might be for that. Actually i don't have access to change properties each time. Need of admin password. So i cant try that for today. Tomorrow i will try that n leave you a comment. Thank you so much for helping. :)

Answer (score -1):

You could take a look at the [Audio API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API), but I don't think they can know if the audio driver is present and working on the system. Then you should look at the browser compatibility that I think it's not available for old ones.